# How do I correctly process input in this Python local chatting server

Tags: python, networking, connection, chat

So I've got this python server which is suppossed to return to the client the same input he/she entered but with "Ok you said:" in front. For example, if the client received the input "Hello",the server should send the following message "Ok you said: Hello". 
The problem is that my code is not saving complete words as input, only single letters. If the client was trying to write "hello", the moment he/she writes the 1rst letter "h", it would automatically receive "Ok you said: h". The client is created simply by writting "telnet localhost" plus the port number in Window's CMD. Hopefully I made myself clear. Thanks in advance. I'm a beginner so you guys might find other errors in my code, suggestions are very welcome!

Code:

```
#Server.py

#Importing Modules
import socket, sys, thread

#Variables
HOST = '' # I do this to be able to connect to all available computers
PORT = 1234 # Arbitrarily chosen

#Creating socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Binding socket
try:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error code : ' + str(msg[0]) + 'Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()
print 'Socket bind complete'
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening...'


#Function for creating threads for every connection
def clientThread(conection):
    #Welcome Message
    conn.send('Welcome to the chat room. In order to exit type "exit-room" ' )

    #infinite loop so that function does not terminate and thread does not end
    while True:
        #receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024) 
        reply = 'Ok You said: ' + data
        if data == 'exit-room':
            break
        conn.sendall(reply)
    conn.close()

while True:
    #wait for incoming connection
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    # display client info
    print 'Connected with ' +addr[0] + ':' +str(addr[1])
    #now keep talking with client
    thread.start_new_thread(clientThread,((conn,)))

s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two-fold:

1. Windows telnet sends your keystrokes to the server *immediately*. It does not do line-buffering like the Unix version does.
2. `conn.recv` blocks until it receives *any* data from the client. Since Windows telnet is sending the keystrokes as they happen, `conn.recv` will never return more than 1 character at a time.

The solution would be to implement line-buffering on the server side:

```
# oops! you seemed to have misnamed the parameter, so I fixed it for you
def clientThread (conn):
    try:
        conn.send('Welcome to the chat room. In order to exit type "exit-room" ' )
        # makefile creates a file-like object (with a readline method)
        # from a socket. "r" means read-only mode, and 1 means line-buffered
        connfile = conn.makefile("r", 1)
        try:
            while True:
                # readline will block until a newline '\n' is encountered
                # or the stream is closed
                data = connfile.readline(1024)
                # the readline method includes the trailing newlines,
                # so we want to strip them
                data = data.rstrip("\r\n")
                reply = 'Ok You said: ' + data
                if data == 'exit-room':
                    break
                conn.sendall(reply + "\r\n")
        finally:
            connfile.close()
    finally:
        # put this line in a finally block so it gets
        # executed even when an exception is thrown
        conn.close()
```

The parameters for `socket.makefile` are the same as the parameters for the built-in `open` function:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: +1. I agree that `.readline()` is required for his application. I also think he should not use the buggy telnet.  There are other telnet clients for Windows, or he could use netcat. And congratulations on your first answer!